# Generate Multiple methods using Reflection

Tags: .net, reflection.emit

I would like to know how I can generate multiple type methods using Reflection.
Example :

```
class A() {

 public void CoreMethod1() {

 }

 public void CoreMethod2() {

 }

 // .. 20 such core methods

 public void Method1() {
   //some initializations
   //call to CoreMethod1();
 }


 public void Method2() {
   //some initializations
   //call to CoreMethod2();
 }

 // i need 20 such methods which will call their respective CoreMethods

 //Method1(),Method2() are similar except for their call to the core method. i.e Every respective method will call its coremethod. Ex : Method1() -> CoreMethod1(), Method2() -> CoreMethod2()
}
```

My question, can I generate Method1(), Method2(), Method3().. dynamically to call their respective core methods. Is there a better way to get this done ?

Answer (score 2):

Probably worth looking into one of IL rewriting libraries:

- Automapper http://automapper.codeplex.com/
- LinFu http://code.google.com/p/linfu/
- PostSharp http://www.sharpcrafters.com/

If you can't work out how to make one of those work for you, have a look at manual `Reflection.Emit`. This [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Creating_Dynamic_Types.aspx) is probably the most detailed source doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple code-generator using **T4 templates**. Here are some good resources.

- http://www.olegsych.com/2008/09/t4-tutorial-creatating-your-first-code-generator/
- http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc308634.aspx
- http://www.pnpguidance.net/Screencast/T4TemplatesVisualStudioCodeGenerationScreencast.aspx